# Although vs. In spite of

Tags: word-order, conjunctions

> Although she was told she would get the job, she didn't get it.
>
> In spite of telling she would get the job, she didn't get it.
>
> In spite of being told she would get the job, she didn't get it.
>
> In spite of the fact that she was told she would get the job, she didn't get it.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1):

> Although she was told she would get the job, she didn't get it.

This sounds ok.

> In spite of telling she would get the job, she didn't get it.

This is not right. You can't use *telling* here without an object and optional subject (with no explicit subject the implication is that *she* told someone). You could say: "In spite of *Mary* telling her she would get the job, she didn't get it." or "In spite of [her] telling me she would get the job, she didn't."

> In spite of being told she would get the job, she didn't get it.

This is also ok.

> In spite of the fact that she was told she would get the job, she didn't get it.

This is also grammatical, but I think it's too verbose.

Another word you could use that's synonymous with *in spite of* is *despite* - see [this article](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/in-spite-of-and-despite). E.g. "Despite being told she would get the job, she did not." or "Despite John telling her she would get the job, she did not."

Answer (score 0):

They are almost entirely synonymous and interchangeable. One dictionary definition of "although" is actually "in spite of".

However, my opinion is that "in spite of" tends to be reserved for when two things are in conflict or contradictory, while "although" can be used more liberally for interesting asides or exceptions to rules.

For example:

> Although we don't normally vacation abroad, this year we are going to Spain.

People tend to say "in spite of *the fact* that [x], [y] happened", but in this example, there isn't really any solid "fact" - saying that something isn't "normally" the case allows for exceptions, so this isn't so strong of a contradiction.

In your example about someone being told they would get a job, I would want to know *who* told them they would get the job. If they were told by the person hiring that they would then their rejection is in direct conflict with that, and "in spite of" sounds right. If on the other hand the person was told they would get it by well-meaning friends and relatives out of over-confidence, then this is not so much of a conflict as a case of expectation not being met. I would personally use "although" in such a case.

Answer (score 0):

They are all correct, however the best between them (for me) are:

> Although she was told she would get the job, she didn't get it.

and:

> In spite of being told she would get the job, she didn't get it.

The two others looks a little heavy.